# external integer constant

Tags: objective-c

this is working fine but it does produce a warning:

`extern int const SCREEN_WIDTH;`

Need I be concerned about doing this? It functions exactly as intended.

The warning I get is:

`SCREEN_WIDTH initialized and declared extern`

and

`extern variable has an initializer`

Comment: You should be concerned with ALL warnings.

Comment: i agree Joe, thanks. it's why I posted here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like where you set the `SCREEN_WIDTH` constant's value, you still have the `extern` keyword. Something like:

`extern int const SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024;`

If so, remove the `extern` keyword. It should only be present where you *declare* the constant, not where you *define* it. :)

Comment: geez that was silly. i've been coding too long today to miss such simple problems. thanks